# Minimizing set intersection/block design

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

I asked this question on the CS theory stack exchange, but didn't get an answer. Was wondering whether anyone here might have some insight. Thanks in advance for any help.

Given 3 parameters $s, r$ and $t$, where $r \leq t$, I want to construct $t$ sets such that each integer $\{1, \ldots, s\}$ appears in exactly $r$ of these sets. The question is:

> Is it possible to construct $t$ sets such that the size of the maximum pairwise intersection between any two $t_i, t_j$ is $\leq k$? What is the complexity of this decision problem? Is minimizing the maximum pairwise intersection between the sets $\mathsf{NP}$-hard?

A comment on the CS Theory stackexchange pointed out that this probably is not NP-complete, since verifying the intersection of all of the sets is quadratic in t and therefore exponential in the size of the input.

There is a lower bound on the max pairwise intersection given by ceiling(number of identical value pairs / number of set pairs), $\lceil (s \cdot {r \choose 2}) / {t \choose 2} \rceil$. This is a natural value for $k$ above, making the question whether there exists an assignment that achieves this bound.

The problem seems related to, but slightly different from, the [block design problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design). In the block design problem, there is a parameter $\lambda$ that dictates in how many of the $t$ sets each pair of integers in $\{1, \ldots, s\}$ must appear, so if $\lambda$ is 1, the maximum pairwise intersection between sets is 1 (since each pair of values appears in at most 1 set together). I've seen claims that deciding the existence of a block design is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete, but no actual proof - would also appreciate any link to such a proof.

Comment: I wonder if you ever answered your own question or did any further work?  Self answers are allowed and even encouraged.  :)